# c# WinForms reusable timer duplicating eventhandler

Tags: c#, timer, eventhandler

I'm trying to understand the timer class and the event handling that is associated to it.  I have an application that will need to call an event at a specific time dependant on the data pulled from the database.  Naturally scheduled tasks is not suitable for this.

Here's the code that I am trying to understand

```
        private Timer setTimer = new Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TimedProcess(null, null);

    }

    private void SetTimer(DateTime dtNextStop)
    {
        TimeSpan span = dtNextStop - DateTime.Now;
        int ms = (int)span.TotalMilliseconds;
        setTimer.Interval = ms;
        setTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimedProcess);
        setTimer.Start();
    }


    public void TimedProcess(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setTimer.Stop();
        setTimer.Dispose();
        txtLog.Text = txtLog.Text = "Tick " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "\r\n" + txtLog.Text;
        SetTimer(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(4));
    }
```

I was trying to be smart (haha failed at that one) by declaring the timer globally to save on resources and reuse this for the next time section.
I noticed that the application was leaking memory so I created a textbox to output the ticks.  This produced some strange results.  I'm obviously doing something wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Tick 18:44:50
Tick 18:44:50
Tick 18:44:50
Tick 18:44:50
Tick 18:44:50
Tick 18:44:50
Tick 18:44:50
Tick 18:44:50
Tick 18:44:46
Tick 18:44:46
Tick 18:44:46
Tick 18:44:46
Tick 18:44:42
Tick 18:44:42
Tick 18:44:38
Tick 18:44:34
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `SetTimer` is attaching the event handler again, you only need to do that once.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things wrong with your code; I'm not sure which is causing what you see as "the problem."

For starters, you're only ever using one `Timer` object, but you are apparently `Dispose()`-ing it with every call to `TimedProcess`.  I strongly recommend not continuing to use an object you've disposed (or, to put it another way, not disposing an object you intend to keep using).

Next, you're registering for the `setTimer.Tick` event every time `SetTimer` is called.  That's probably why you're seeing more lines for each firing of the `Tick` event.

Is `setTimer` a `System.Timers.Timer` or a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`?  If the latter, it needs to be associated with a control, and if the former, you need to `Invoke` changes you make to the GUI when the timer is fired, as it'll be fired on a background thread.